# CropperJS and getting the canvas without cropping

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, cropperjs

I'm using the Vue CropperJS library, and I'm trying to use the cropperjs library. I've customized it in a way so that you can edit the picture without a cropper, by just adjusting the picture inside the container. I've done this by wrapping it around a container with defined widths and heights, and gave it the 100% height style.

[image]

[image]

The problem here is that I can only get either the image from a crop area, or get the entire original image from this.$refs.cropper.getCroppedCanvas(). I've tried to work around the getCroppedCanvas(), but I was wondering if there was a more straight forward way to get the current image that the user got.